# Browser expects a short variable input unable to pass in with python Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am working on automating some interactions with a website (which I don't have access to the base code). One of the text input boxes I believe is expecting a 'short' integer value. However nothing I do through python/selenium will successfully pass the value to the browser. Whenever I do I get an Invalid input error.

I have tried many variations of `driver.send_keys()` with the value as a string, int, unicode string, long to no avail.

I have also tried sending the value through javascript:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('short_input').setAttribute('value', arguments[0])", '10')
```

Where I have also tried passing in a 'short' variable through `a = array('h')` and `numpy.short('10')`.

When I get the invalid input error I am able to manually clear it out by clicking on the input box and then clicking away. I assume that this is because then the value is reset to be a short integer as the code expects.

Is there anyway to do this through selenium? When I try `element.click()` it doesn't clear out the error as it does manually. Or is there another way I missed to pass in a short variable?

The relevant HTML of the value I'm trying to modify is:

```html
<input id="x-auto-23-input" class="N0-com-sencha-gxt-theme-base-client-field-TwinTriggerFieldDefaultAppearance-TwinTriggerFieldStyle-field E1-com-sencha-gxt-theme-base-client-field-TwinTriggerFieldDefaultAppearance-TwinTriggerFieldStyle-text A1-com-sencha-gxt-theme-base-client-field-TwinTriggerFieldDefaultAppearance-TwinTriggerFieldStyle-invalid P0-com-sencha-gxt-theme-base-client-field-TwinTriggerFieldDefaultAppearance-TwinTriggerFieldStyle-focus" type="text" value="" style="width:142px;" tabindex="0">
```

Nothing I see in it hints as to why it is different from a normal text input box. Yet when I do a `element.clear()` followed by `element.send_keys(10)` and then try to save the change by clicking the browsers 'OK' button I get an error that it is an invalid entry.

Comment: Is there any way you demonstrate the problem or make it reproducible for us? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately not that I can think of, since the code is confidential and I don't know enough about their code to write something similar. I saw a very similar problem when the browser code was expecting a 'long' variable however I was able to get around it with: driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", element, long(10))`  But since python doesn't have a short() casting type I am trying to think of another work around.

Comment: How is it that a webpage is expecting a certain type to be submitted? Surely it would just take a string input from the user through a form, etc. and convert it to a particular type? I don't understand. How does the user manually submit a value for that field?

Comment: It seems like you are spot on when a user manually enters a string it converts it to the particular type. But for some reason when you pass it the string via Selenium it doesn't. I am pretty new to selenium and don't really understand what is going on underneath the covers but it doesn't seem to fully act as a manual interaction would.

Comment: My guess is that you are doing something unexpected. :) Please post the relevant HTML of the field you are trying to enter the number into and maybe we can help you figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Given the HTML provided, it should be as simple as

```
driver.find_element_by_id("x-auto-23-input").send_keys("abc")
```

You should be able to send a string because that's what the user would enter into the page itself. The internals of the page may convert that string into another data type but the page will do that work for you... you shouldn't have to worry about that.

Have you tried this? What was the result?

Comment: it does work in so far that I see the value show up on the GUI, however I get an error that it is of an invalid value (where the value is 10 and the correct range is 0-250). As I had a similar issue previously where I was able to get it to be the 'correct' value by passing in a long I am trying to figure out a hack to trick it into thinking I passed in a 'short' value. I believe it must be the code verifying that is blocking me, which I have no access to.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt at setting the value using JavaScript cannot work. This is what you have (reformatted to avoid a super-long line):

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('short_input')"
                      ".setAttribute('value', arguments[0])", '10')
```

What this does is set the *attribute* of your `input` element, which is completely useless. The attribute is used when the `input` is created and then it serves no further purpose. What you'd have to change is the *property* of your `input` element:

```
driver.execute_script(
    "document.getElementById('short_input').value = arguments[0]", '10')
```

You may in the past have used `element.set_attribute("value", whatever)` but this works because Selenium silently changes the *property* rather than the *value*.

So we know why *that attempt* did not work. Now, it's a mystery as to why using `.send_keys()` is not working for you. I've just tried on a page I created myself. I had never tried just passing a number to it but just now I tried it and got Selenium to set the input field to the value 10.

Comment: Thank you @Louis I unfortunately have tried that too. Again from my comment to JeffC the value is passed but not accepted by the browser as 'correct'.